# Is it possible to add an event listener to the small buttons in a number input box?

Tags: javascript, html

If for example i had an input box in a shopping basket which is asking for the quantity of the product, I would like to add an event listener to the small buttons to the right of the number in the `<input type=number>` field which change the number accordingly and will update the price.

If this is possible an example would be great.

Thanks.

EDITED

I would also like to stay clear of jQuery please if possible

Comment: you could just use the change/input event

Comment: If your browser supports Shadow DOM, you might be able to get at the buttons. But most browsers don't. Why isn't the input's *change* event enough for you?

Comment: Honestly I hadn't heard of the change event before, but now I have learned it, it is the most suitable solution, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Javascript change event:

```
document.getElementById("product").addEventListener("change", function( event ) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }, false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7csoL5we/)

**Updating price which changing value of product:**

```
document.getElementById("product").addEventListener("change", function( event ) {
    var product = parseInt(event.target.value);
    document.getElementById("price").value = product *2;
  }, false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7csoL5we/1/)

Comment: +1 for this solution.
May I add that the little buttons depend only on the browser, because it's yet an HTML5 reference. 
Many browsers won't show any little button whatsoever, until a potential new version that will support it.

Comment: @AlexPierstoval `input type="number"` is supported in most all modern browser. And If HTML 5 Input Types are not supported on a browser, they will behave as regular text fields. Then change event will not work, so you can use `keyup` event then.